# Save battery on SNES Super Mario World cartridge?

Tags: hardware, super-mario-world

I've managed to get a SNES with Super Mario World from a friend of mine, but the game won't save my progress. I Googled around a bit and figured out that SNES games use a battery to save their files, and since the cartridge was old, I'd need to replace it.

So far so good, but when I opened the cartridge, I couldn't find an old battery or even space for one. Is this one different? Is it even official? How do I fix my problem?

[image: Cartridge]
[image: Cartridge]

Comment: This cartdrige _works?_ It seems to be lacking, well, everything compared to [this one](http://bc-programming.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Super-Mario-World-Innards.jpg)

Comment: FWIW, my own Super Mario World still has my save files intact.

Comment: It works and I've played up to World 3 with it in one sitting, also, the designs of both cartridges seem to be different

Comment: It's most likely counterfeit. Genuine Nintendo cartridges should have the Nintendo copyright on the circuit board. Possibly the counterfeiters didn't bother with SRAM and just copied the ROM, though I'm not sure how anyone could prove it.

Comment: @PaulO. I'm not even sure how it does anything without chips on the board.

Comment: @121Gigamatts World 3? The "worlds" in SMW aren't numbered...

Comment: @Mego fine, Vanilla Dome, whatever. I'm bummed this is counterfeit :\ Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, this is a counterfeit cartridge.  That black spot contains a tiny chip under it which contains the ROM data.

This was likely created (guesstimate) well after the lifecycle of the SNES.  Also, I don't have a SNES cartridge near me at the moment but I *think* that case is not a legit donor case either.

You didn't post images of the other side, but if we can see the label we could definitely confirm if it's 100% fake.

Where and when did your friend get this?  This would have never saved data.